# C++ "std::cin >> " is not pausing to read input from Emacs shell

Tags: spacemacs, shell, shell-command

The following program is from https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/tool/emacs/programming/

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int howmany;

  std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
  std::cin >> howmany;
  std::cout << "howmany=" << howmany << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

It compiled and ran in Emacs shell:

```
SPC c C  (compile)
SPC !    (shell-command)
Shell command: ./total
```

The program did not stop and prompt for input.
The program just blows by the "std::cin >> howmany;" and assigns 0 to howmany.
I did not enter any input.
For one second the mini buffer said:

```
Enter a number: 0
```

The *Messages* buffer says:

```
user-error: Minibuffer window is not active
Enter a number: howmany=0
```

The executable works fine when run from Bash shell:

```
$ ./total
Enter a number: 2 
howmany=2
```

Why does std::cin work in Bash shell, but not in Emacs shell?

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq-w32/Subprocess-buffering.html
says:

```
having an explicit flag to control their buffering behavior,
typically -i for interactive, or by a special environment variable.
```

Would that fix it?  Where does the -i flag go?

I am using Emacs 25.2.1 with Evil Spacemacs and Ivy on Linux.

**UPDATE_1**

The interactive program works when shell-commend is called with asynchronously option:

```
SPC SPC (counsel-M-x) async-shell-command

Enter a number: 2
howmany=2
```

From Emacs help describe-function shell-command:

```
shell-command is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘simple.el’.

...

If COMMAND ends in ‘&’, execute it asynchronously.
The output appears in the buffer ‘*Async Shell Command*’.
That buffer is in shell mode.  You can also use
‘async-shell-command’ that automatically adds ‘&’.

Otherwise, COMMAND is executed synchronously.  The output appears in
the buffer ‘*Shell Command Output*’.
```

Why would interactive program not work on a synchronous system?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_system

I am thinking of binding `async-shell-command` to `SPC !`.
Is there a disadvantage to always running `async-shell-command` instead of the default `shell-command`?

Comment: `shell-command` isn't intended for use with interactive programs like yours. You should try using `shell`, `term`or `ansi-term` for these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

async-shell-command works with interactive programs.
async-shell does not.

Emacs has OS command-line interfaces and terminal emulators.
It's not always obvious which one to use.  Here is a comparison:
http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_shell_vs_term_vs_ansi-term_vs_eshell.html

When to use a dedicated terminal:
http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_shell_vs_terminal.html

Comment: `eshell` is an Emacs alternative to Unix shells, but the other things are just interfaces to those same shells.